# How to calculate the SVD of a $3×3$ diagonal only matrix without computing the eigenvalues explicitly.

Tags: svd, orthogonal-matrices, singularity, singular-values, unitary-matrices

Given $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $$

What would be its SVD?

Key facts we can use:
a) Singular values in the Sigma matrix are on the principal diagonal in decreasing order.
b) Identity matrix is Unitary.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $AA^t$ are 1, 4 and 0. Therefore, the singular values of $A$ are equal to $2, 1, 0$, after sorting.

In such a simple case, the SVD can be obtained by rewriting $A$ as, where the $e_i$ are the natural basis vectors:

$$A = 1\, e_1 e_1^t -2\, e_2 e_2^t + 0\, e_3 e_3^t$$

and then the SVD in sum form:

$$ A = 2\, (-e_2) {e_2}^t + 1\, e_1 e_1^t + 0\, e_3 e_3^t$$

In equivalent matrix form:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Is there a way to deduce this without computing any of the eigen vectors or eigenvalues

Comment: You can try to multiply $A$ on both sides by identity matrix, modify the identity matrix on the left such that -2 becomes 2, and then modify both left and right matrices such that 1 and 2 in the diagonal matrix are exchanged. But it won't be really simpler.

Comment: Perfect. That is it! Thanks.

Comment: Actually, follow up question @Damien. This SVD is not unique, right? What could be an alternate set of 3 matrices that is also a solution?

Comment: The fact to sort the singular values is a convention. You could modify the order. Moreover, look at the sum formula: you could modify the position of the - sign, or introduce new ones and replace all $e_1$ by $-e_1$ etc.

Comment: Note that I modified the matrices, but former one was correct too, less logical

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!